# Drop down selectlist for next 10 years

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I need to write a function that return next 10 year selectlist.
I am hard coding at the moment and still working on how to get this done. How to write a function that could return any period that I want e.g next 20 years

```
//View
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CardExpiryYear, vmConstants.listExpiryYears)

//Partial Class
public static partial class vmConstants
{
public static SelectList listExpiryYears = new SelectList(new[]
        {
                new{  Name ="" , ID = ""}, 
                new{  Name ="2014" , ID = "2014"}, 
                new{  Name ="2015" , ID = "2015"}, 
                new{  Name ="2016" , ID = "2016"}, 
                new{  Name ="2017" , ID = "2017"}, 
                new{  Name ="2018" , ID = "2018"}, 
                new{  Name ="2019" , ID = "2019"}, 
                new{  Name ="2020" , ID = "2020"}, 
                new{  Name ="2021" , ID = "2021"}, 
                new{  Name ="2022" , ID = "2022"}, 
                new{  Name ="2023" , ID = "2023"}, 
                new{  Name ="2024" , ID = "2024"}, 
                new{  Name ="2025" , ID = "2025"},
                new{  Name ="2026" , ID = "2026"},
        },
        "ID", "Name", 1);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to use [`Enumerable.Range`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.range%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [`DateTime.Now.Year`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Something like this should get you started.

```
var years = Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Now.Year, 10);
var select = new SelectList(years.Select(y => new SelectListItem() 
{ 
    Text = y.ToString(), Value = y.ToString() 
}));
```

Comment: public static List<SelectListItem> listExpiryYearstry()
        {        
            var years = Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Year + 10);


            Payment payment = new Payment();

            payment.ListToUse = new SelectList(years.Select(y => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = y.ToString(),
                Value = y.ToString()
            })).ToList();

            return payment.ListToUse;
        }

Comment: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<Components.Models.Payment>' does not contain a definition for 'DropDownListFor' and the best extension method overload. public static List<SelectListItem> listExpiryYearstry()
{        
            var years = Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Year + 10);


            Payment payment = new Payment();

            payment.ListToUse = new SelectList(years.Select(y => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = y.ToString(),
                Value = y.ToString()
            })).ToList();

            return payment.ListToUse;
        }

Comment: @user3650406 Not sure what issue you're having exactly. Might be best to ask a new question. I can say that the code I posted should live in the controller, and it should set a `ViewBag.SomeName`, and then you should do `@Html.DropDownList("SomeName")` and that should get you started.